# Extracting Column Data with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, average

I am co-op student and new powershell user, and I am trying to make a script that extracts information for a column within a CSV file and outputs the average to a hashtable.  The file in question is a log file that contains headers with names pertaining to specific components.  The data under these headers are mostly temperature values for which I would like to perform various operations on.  Here is what I have:

```
function createTable{
param ([parameter(mandatory=$true)]$filename)  
$d = ipcsv $filename
$rowsize = ($d | measure-object).count
$table = @{}
$headername = $d | get-member | select 'membertype','Name' | where-object {$_.membertype -eq "Noteproperty"} | select 'Name'
$table.add("Log Start Time", ($d | select -index 2 | select 'Time').time)
$table.add("Log End Time", ($d | select -last 1 | select 'Time').time)
$totaltemp = 0
$count = 0
for($i = 0; $i -lt $p.count; $i++){
    $d | select $headername[$i].'Name' | foreach-object{if($_.($headername[$i].'Name') -ne 'Time'){
        if (([int64]::TryParse($d.($headername[$i].'name')[3] , [ref]""))){
            for ($j = 3; $j -lt $u ; $j++){  
                $totaltemp = $totaltemp + $d.($headername[$i].'name')[$j]
                $count++            

            }  

        }   


    }
    if ($count -ne 0){
    $table.add($headername.name[$i], $totaltemp/$count)
}
}
}
write-output $table
};set-alias ct createtable
```

I'm sure this needs a lot of work, but I am willing to learn.  My variable $u measures the number of rows in the file, and my variable $p isolates for the header name.  I am trying to check that the row value for each header is numerical and then attempt to add them up to take the average.  My first for loop is meant to execute based on the number of columns, while the second loop is intended to execute based on the numbers of rows, with the first 2 rows excluded.

Comment: this is a good example of why to use meaningful variable names...

Comment: Fair point.  I've edited my post and changed the variables to be more descriptive.